# How to use a nested property as a named param in a hibernate query?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, parameters, param

I really want to use nested property as a named param in a hibernate query.
So I can maintenance my param bean more elegantly.

For example, I want write my HQL like:

```
"......
where
    employee.age >= :age.min
  and
    employee.age <= :age.max
  and
    employee.name = :name"
```

and put all the params into ONE paramBean,
and in this paramBean, there is a nested bean (named "age"),
and the nested bean have 2 properties： min and max.

But the problem is:

1. The HQL syntax does not support nested property as named param:
   Hibernate will throw a exception, because it does not allow using
   "." in the param name.
2. In the
   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.setProperties(Object)
   method, the implementation code is:

   ```
       Getter getter = ReflectHelper.getGetter( clazz, namedParam );
       Class retType = getter.getReturnType();
       final Object object = getter.get( bean );
   ```

It use the getter method on the param bean, so it can not retrieve the nested property.

I had to create lots of delegate method in the param bean, to access the nested property:

```
public int getAgeMin() {
    return this.age.getMin();
}


public int getAgeMax() {
    return this.age.getMax();
}
```

and write the HQL like:

```
"......
where
    employee.age >= :ageMin
  and
    employee.age <= :ageMax
  and
    employee.name = :name"
```

This problem bothered me for years.

And I finally find a way to fix it.

Here is the solution:

1. For problem (1): In HQL: use "_" as a escape char for the "."

HQL likes:

```
"......
where
    employee.age >= :age_min
  and
    employee.age <= :age_max
  and
    employee.name = :name"
```

2. For problem (2): write some helper methods, to set all param values
   for the HQL.

The code of the helper methods are:

```
private void setParameters(final Query query, final Object paramBean) {
    for (String namedParam : query.getNamedParameters()) {
        try {
            // !!! Fix problem (1) !!!
            // unescape the param name into nested property name
            String nestedPropName = StringUtils.replace(namedParam, "_",
                    ".");

            // !!! Fix problem (2) !!!
            // retrieve the nested property, using Apache Commons BeanUtils
            // see: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/
            Object paramValue = PropertyUtils.getNestedProperty(paramBean,
                    nestedPropName);

            Class<?> paramType = null;
            if (paramValue != null) {
                paramType = paramValue.getClass();
            }

            if ((paramType != null)
                    && Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(paramType)) {
                query.setParameterList(namedParam,
                        (Collection<?>) paramValue);
            } else if ((paramType != null) && paramType.isArray()) {
                query.setParameterList(namedParam, (Object[]) paramValue);
            } else {
                Type type = this.guessType(paramType);
                query.setParameter(namedParam, paramValue, type);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}


private Type guessType(final Class<?> clazz) throws HibernateException {
    SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactoryImplementor = (SessionFactoryImplementor) this.sessionFactory;

    String typeName = clazz.getName();
    Type type = sessionFactoryImplementor.getTypeResolver().heuristicType(
            typeName);
    boolean serializable = type != null && type instanceof SerializableType;
    if (type == null || serializable) {
        try {
            sessionFactoryImplementor.getEntityPersister(clazz.getName());
        } catch (MappingException me) {
            if (serializable) {
                return type;
            } else {
                throw new HibernateException(
                        "Could not determine a type for class: " + typeName);
            }
        }
        return this.getSession().getTypeHelper().entity(clazz);
    } else {
        return type;
    }
}
```

The important points are **[!!! Fix problem (1) !!!]** and **[!!! Fix problem (2) !!!]**,

all the other code are simply copied from org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl

Answer (score 0):

How about using an [example query Criteria](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch17.html#querycriteria-examples) instead:

```
Age age = ...;
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setAge(age);
Example example = Example.create(employee);             
List results = session.createCriteria(Employee.class)
    .add(example)
    .list();
```

This is close as possible to having nested filtering parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Why I need this?

1. This is not only a problem for "SELECT", but also happen to
   "DELETE", "UPDATE"
2. If I need to write a very complex query, I prefer HQL, but not
   Criteria
3. Nested Param Bean/Nested Property make me able to maintenance my
   param beans more elegantly. For example, I have a class:
   [ValueRange>], which has 4 properties:

> ```
> public class ValueRange<T extends Comparable<T>> {
>   private T min;
>
>   private boolean includeMin;
>
>   private T max;
>
>   private boolean includeMax;
>
> .....
> }
> ```

I like to use this container Bean to present all the ValueRange condition, likes:

```
where
....
    employee.birthDate >= :dateRange.min
  and
    employee.birthDate <= :dateRange.max
....
    employee.salary >= :salaryRange.min
  and
    employee.salary <= :salaryRange.max
```

4. And even more complex mode: I like to:

(4-1)use a DepartmentCondition bean to present a search condition
    for Department.

(4-2)use a EmployeeCondition bean to present a search condition for Employee.

(4-3)use DepartmentCondition as a Nested Bean of EmployeeCondition to present a search condition for the Employee's Department

(4-4)I like to write HQL like this:

```
where
....
    employee.birthDate >= :dateRange.min
  and
    employee.birthDate <= :dateRange.max
....
    employee.salary >= :salaryRange.min
  and
    employee.salary <= :salaryRange.max
....
    employee.department.code = :department.code
and
    employee.department.name = :department.name
```

by using this design pattern, the DepartmentCondition bean can be a common bean, used for both Department query, and Employee query.

So I can maintenance my param bean more elegantly.